# zsh: run function after specific command and argument

Tags: shell, homebrew

Currently structuring my dotfiles and figured i would make a copy of all installed homebrew and cask packages. This is very nicely done via [homebrew-bundle](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-bundle).

However, I want to add some automation to this and have a new bundle generated for every package i install or uninstall. From what i understand, I can use the `chpwd()` hook function to execute a function after every command. This works nicely, but I am having problems with detecting exactly when `brew install` or `brew uninstall` is being run..

#### How can I get the name of the command being run inside the function, given the following:

```
newbrewfile() {
  echo "${0}" # returns name of function ("newbrewfile") instead of command..
  # if brew install or brew uninstall is run, then execute this afterwards 
    brew bundle dump --file="~/.dotfiles/Brewfile" --force 
}

function chpwd() {
  newbrewfile
}
```

Any and all pointers appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: You might want to create functions `brewi`/`brewu` (naming obv. according to your preference) which you use instead of `brew install` or `brew uninstall`. Might simplify things a bit.

Comment: @Panki Sure, but i think you might be misunderstanding. The problem is that i seemingly cannot access the command ($0) because the function is triggered in a hook. How can i detect when brew install or brew uninstall is run?

Comment: You don't need to if you use self defined functions instead... :)